# can other sites call facebook callback url

Tags: php, facebook

I am creating a facebook web app. My question is can other websites call my facebook deauthorize url by sending the user_id information. Is it possible.

If this is possbile how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it is possible.  Facebook signs these requests so that you can verify that they are authenticate.  Here is a good tutorial with a code example for how to parse and handle deauthorizations: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/track-users-who-are-removing-your-facebook-application/